# Build libqtwebkit4.so from sources

Tags: qt, webkit

I'm trying to build libqtwebkit4 from sources : https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtwebkit-source
Everything goes right:

- I have instilled all dependencies (gtk3, glib, pango,...)
- ./autogen.sh
- make  make install

But I can't find final libqtwekin4 library. How can I get libqtwebkit from sources?

p.s. I know that I can install package , but I need custom library. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have managed it with [this official QT snapshot](http://download.qt-project.org/snapshots/qt/4.8/2014-01-23_453/)
You just need to download the `tar.gz` and unpack

```
./configure -webkit -nomake demos -nomake examples
make && make install
```

If you have problems with `gold-liner`, you should comment this line in `/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/common.pri`

```
# QMAKE_LFLAGS+=-fuse-ld=gold
```